# Gridview get selected value but receive value from higher row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I try get value from selected gridview row, but i receive the value from row, which is higher in gridview. I think that is problem with counter, but I can't find it.

c#

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    m = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text;
```

asp

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnDataBound="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="490px" AllowSorting="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1" EditIndex="5" SelectedIndex="0" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" DataKeyNames="Idoferty">
```

Comment: Your code does not show us much, where is that counter, of which you speak?

Comment: I suppose it's coutner, but I don't know which :). I always receive value from higher row.

Comment: Try removing EditIndex="5" SelectedIndex="0" from the control, I am not sure when your selection changes, but it's possible that SelectedIndex overwrites your selection.

Comment: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: @IlyaNemtsev it didn't help. Which code can I paste to help you?

Comment: Put a breaker on m=...Show us the screenshot of what value m has and tell us which row you clicked.

Comment: What the heck is this?   OnDataBound="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"

Comment: @IlyaNemtsev screenshot from gridview https://i.imgur.com/fBxSVVu.png

Comment: Steve has a point, looking at SelectedIndexChanged on Databound does not seem correct.

Comment: It should work. if it doesn't, there is the problem outside of the code you are showing. plz show more code.